# A curve has to stay within a matrix

Tags: c#, wpf, matrix, curve

I have a matrix with an uneven number of columns per row. The number of columns decreases with increasing rows. Now there is a curve drawn on top of the matrix.
A requirement is, that the curve has to be completely within the matrix.

The picture is a matrix where the curve leaves the boundaries of the matrix. This is what I have to fix.
[image: Matrix with curve]

The algorithm that calculates the curve is not aware of the size of the matrix.

The question is: What is the best way to fulfill this requirement?
Will the algorithm that calculates the curve have to change to be aware of the matrix dimensions?
Or can I change the curve afterwards to "live" inside the matrix?
What would you recommend?

The expected curve would look like this:
[image: expected curve with interpolated points]
I added blue dots to the points that make up the polyline. The little black dots on the line represent calculated points based on linear interpolation. Each of these calculated Points can be tested to determine whether they are inside or outside of the matrix. The actual matrix has more columns and rows but displaying it does not add to the clarity of the task at hand or the possible approach to solve it.

I created a little demo:

**MainWindows.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="InsideMatrix.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:InsideMatrix"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="525" x:Name="Main">
    <Grid>
        <local:Matrix/>
        <Polyline Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" Points="{Binding Curve, ElementName=Main}" Visibility="Visible"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace InsideMatrix
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private PointCollection curve;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                this.Curve = this.CalculateCurve();
            }
        }

        private PointCollection CalculateCurve()
        {
            // This is just a stub for an algorith that will calculate a curve
            return new PointCollection()
            {
                new Point(57, 24),
                new Point(114, 48),
                new Point(171, 72),
                new Point(228, 96),
                new Point(456, 153)
            };
        }

        public PointCollection Curve
        {
            get { return this.curve; }
            set
            {
                this.curve = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Matrix.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="InsideMatrix.Matrix"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:insideMatrix="clr-namespace:InsideMatrix"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**Matrix.xaml.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace InsideMatrix
{
    public partial class Matrix : UserControl
    {
        private int width = 57;
        private int height = 24;
        private int[] cellsPerRow = { 7, 7, 4, 4, 2, 2 };


        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
        {
            base.OnRender(drawingContext);
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this)) return;
            Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 1);
            int row = 0;
            foreach (var cells in cellsPerRow)
            {
                row++;
                for (int column = 7; column > 7 - cells; column--)
                {
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent), pen, new Rect(column * width, row * height, width, height));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep the line sticky on the top.. .and it will always be completely inside the grid.. ..or better.. ..what are the other requirements?

Comment: The curve is calculated based on optional predefined points along the horizontal axis. The curve between the points are interpolated. This can lead to the described problem where all the predefined points are in the matrix, but it is calculated to traverse the edges of the matrix. Another requirement is that the surface between the lower edge of the matrix and the curve have to be filled with a color, but this will not be so difficult once the problem of the curve inside the matrix is solved.

Comment: is this a recursive matrix? I can see Matrix user control is creating its own instance within it.

Comment: appreciated if you could post an image of your expected output.

Comment: It is not a recursive Matrix. Sorry, it was my mistake. I changed the Matrix.xaml.

Comment: @pushraj: I posted the expected output. Note that the dots are just for illustration purposes and are not part of the expected output.

Comment: Why does the rightmost corner look like it does? It goes (from right to left) straigt to the corner, a bit left, then straight to the next point. Why not straight, straight or straight, up, left, straight?

Comment: I am not able to figure out any algorithm which may fit for the expected output. secondly it does not look a curve either. Could you please explain the expectations bit more in details? my initial thought was something like [this image](http://imgur.com/dp2d749). also what if a point fall out of the matrix?

Comment: @Nico: If you lay the two graphics on top of each other you will see what happens. The curve is following the line from one blue dot to the next until one of the calculated interpolated points is outside of the matrix. Those points outside the matrix are adjusted to the closest point inside the matrix. The curve has to go through the points marked by the blue dots. This is not the case with pushprajs image.